# FileReader doesnot work without choosing a file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used FileReader to read the selected file using javascript. Here is the code

HTML:

```
<img id="preview" ng-src="{{user_picture}}" ng-click="triggerUpload()" alt="" width="160" height="160" class="img-thumbnail" />
<input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().viewImage(this.files)" accept="image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png" id="fileInput" name="filedata" />
```

SCRIPT:

```
$scope.triggerUpload = function () {
    show_image();
}

$scope.list = [];
$scope.viewImage = function (file) {
     show_image(file);        
}



    function show_image(image) { 
        var fileuploader = angular.element("#fileInput");
        fileuploader.on('click', function () {           
            if (image && image[0]) {
                 var reader = new FileReader();            
                 reader.onload = function (e) {
                     $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
                  }
                 reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);                    
               }
             })
        fileuploader.trigger('click');
     }
```

This works fine when I select an file from the upload dialog box. But, when I click 'Cancel' or exit the uploader without selecting any file, I get the error below.

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader':
>   parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

How to solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

> How to solve this problem??

Don't call `show_image` when user selects cancel

```
function show_image(image) {            
        if (image && image[0] && this.files.length) {
            var reader = new FileReader();            
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);                    
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition above checks for `image && image[0]` which (if our guess is correct without more code to explain it) check for this variable to be non-null.

However you are calling `readAsDataURL()` on `this.files[0]`; this variable has nothing to do with `image`, and most likely you are not setting it or it is not a filename when the user has pressed cancel.

Without more code, we cannot guess a more accurate answer...